# Is the number of cards in my opponent's library public knowledge in Magic: The Gathering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The number of cards in players' hands is public knowledge, as is the number of exiled cards and cards in anyone's graveyard. But is the number of cards in your library public knowledge at all times as well? This could strongly affect decisions for players who frequently run mill decks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. From the [comprehensive rules](http://www.wizards.com/magic/comprules/MagicCompRules_20110930.txt):

> 401.3. Any player may count the number of cards remaining in any player's library at any time.

Comment: Note that doing library counts excessively in organized play is grounds for a penalty in the same way that any other time-wasting behavior is. :)

Comment: In MTGO every player's library count is always displayed, so there's never any question, nor any need to stop and count.

Comment: Note: The rules linked to above is old, but the link names will always change.  The page to find the rules is here:  http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules, with the current rules located here:  http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_20140601.pdf